# JPA: No Persistence provider for Entity Manager: using Intellij community edition and Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm learning JPA with Intellij community edition. I've read that it's possible to use it with this Intellij version.

I've made my database on localhost with pgAdmin. I've added external jars to my project (JDBC Postresql driver + javax.presistance). I've made (manually) META-INF folder with persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="testname" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>presistencetest.Car</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://host:localhost:5432/databasename"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgresql"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

When I try to launch simple test (part of code):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testname");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

I get error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testname
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:84)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at presistencetest.Car.main(Car.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Could you post your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the artifact layout , persistence.xml should be located under /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml. Intellij Community does not automatically detect config files as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the provider of JPA, because JPA is only an specification. The most common is Hibernate and EclipseLink.

Here is the tag:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Replace the provider with whatever you want or need.

Comment: That is not the error: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testname